# spring security problem using grails

Tags: facebook, grails, authentication, grails-plugin

I am new to grails and spring security plugin core , but i am facing a problem of

ERROR GrailsExceptionResolver - a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [nayax.SecUserSecRole#nayax.SecUserSecRole : null]

my code is :

```
NayaxUser populateDataFromJson(def user) {
    //todo: HANDLE CASES OF CREATING ROLES FOR USER AND REAUTHENTICATE THEM
    println "#### In FUNCTION ####"
    Facebook existingProfile = Facebook.findByFid(user.id)
    if (existingProfile) {
        println "### User already present in the database ####"
        existingProfile.setUser(existingProfile.user)

        //todo: CREATE ROLE AND REAUTHENTICATE USER
        SecRole secRole1 = SecRole.findByAuthority(SecRoleConstants.ROLE_USER)
        SecUserSecRole.create(existingProfile.user, secRole1)

        //todo: REAUTHENTICATE USER
        springSecurityService.reauthenticate(existingProfile.user.username)

        existingProfile.user.merge()
        return existingProfile.user
    }
    else {
        Facebook facebookObj = new Facebook(fid: user.id, lastLogin: new Date(), creationDate: new Date()).save(flush: true)
        NayaxUser nayaxUser = new NayaxUser(facebookUrl: user.link, fullName: user.name, facebook: facebookObj, username: user.email, password: springSecurityService.encodePassword("pleaseChangeMe"), enabled: true)
        if (nayaxUser.save(flush: true)) {
            println "### WORK DONE , saved user and save the user in session ###"
            facebookObj.setUser(nayaxUser)

            //todo: CREATE ROLE AND REAUTHENTICATE USER
            SecRole secRole = SecRole.findByAuthority(SecRoleConstants.ROLE_USER)
            SecUserSecRole.create(nayaxUser, secRole)

            //todo: REAUTHENTICATE USER
            springSecurityService.reauthenticate(nayaxUser.username)

            nayaxUser.merge()
            return nayaxUser
        }
        else {
            println "### ERROR IN VALIDATING DATA So NOT SETTING THE USER IN SESSION ####"
            nayaxUser.errors.allErrors.each { error ->
                println("### ERROR IS ${error} ####")
            }
            return nayaxUser
        }
    }
}
```

Actually , when i am loggin in from the facebook button and then logging out from my implementation and then logging back again quicky then there is an exception but after logging out i refresh the page a few times the problem disappears. I think something is wrong with my facebook logout implementation or is there something in the code ???

Any suggestions are welcome..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use facebook javascript api for logout before call your logout controller to clear session and etc e.g:

```
if facebook user exists
  logout facebook user with fb js api
  js redirect to logout controller  
else
  redirect user to logout controller
```

This logic should be applied in the frontend of your application assuming that if there isn't facebook user, user will be redirected directly to the logout controller.

I have problems with facebook logout with java and php api from the fb application but in that way  I overcome those problems.